# Dynamic react-redux approach

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I am working on an app that is a report that has multiple participants attached to it. I am using react-redux and my question is how do I manage dynamic number of participants in redux. I have a wizard that stores all info in redux store and at the end of this wizard I want user to tap on Add button in order to add users to this report. I want app user to add as many reprort participants as they want.

Update:
My app has a wizard with 3 steps. First two steps are shown on screens with bunch of checklist items. User checks the boxes and I store everything into the redux store via same reducer. Final step is to add participants of this report and they can be one or many. I have a screen for that but there is only place for one person in the redux.   (Each variable is already filled with info from the first paricipant). I need a way to be able to dynamically add participants to redux. At the end I want to store all of this to database. I have one table for the report and one table for participants. 
I am new to react native and redux. This is my first app in react

Comment: could you elaborate on what you want to do? 
isn't that similar as, eg. a to-do list (adding /removing stuff)? 
where are your problems?

Comment: My problem is that i dont know how to store additions when I have variables that only stores one value per field in the react-redux. when additions are made I want to send all of this to database. I have one table in the database for the report and one table where I can store participants.  Is using arrays solution to my problem? (It is something like to-do list)

Comment: well, could be. but sending stuff to your database is something independent from storing your stuff in your redux store. honestly, i think it would be beneficial if you read some more about handling data in redux or js in general if you're unsure how to store your data-objects